# How to interpret this result in machine learning? What's going wrong in model?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to train my model. I have tried so many parameters and I also increased the number of samples. But I'm unable to predict what's going wrong in my model and what should I do to improve accuracy? Here is the detail of my code. I'm collecting 50 thousand samples for a single class and I'm using 95 percent data for training.

```
def conv2d(input, filter):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(input, filter, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
def max_pool(conv_out1):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(conv_out1, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides= 1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')
input = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 16, 16,1]) 
filter = weight_variable([3, 3, 1,5])
conv_out1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(input,filter))
pooling_out1 = max_pool(conv_out1)
print pooling_out1.get_shape()
pool_list = pooling_out1.get_shape().as_list()
z = pool_list[1]*pool_list[2]*pool_list[3]
W_fc_input = tf.reshape(pooling_out2,[-1,z])
W_fc = weight_variable([z, 25])
entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels=y_)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(entropy)
run_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss)
for i in range(total_train_step):
    batch = Input.train.next_batch(batch_size)
    run_optimizer.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
    if i % FLAGS.step_interval == 0:
       train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
       test_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: Input_test.Samples, y_: InputData.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0})
```

[image: accuracy here]

Comment: May be your data is too noisy, may be your model is too simple, may be you has some mistake in loading and preparing data. Please provide more information.

Comment: I have added more information regarding code

Comment: I tried to add one one convolutional layer but id didn't improved efficiency

Comment: Your code sample looks incomplete - is it all model layers? How do you train it? I can suggest you switch to high level Keras API, and start from working sample like https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py

Comment: I have edited my code to give you more detail. my training and test accuracy are not increasing. I increased number of layers but it didn't work. I increased number of samples at each class but still result was same. I am confused is there anything wrong which samples ?How I can imporve this?

Comment: You don't have dropout layers, so keep_prob actually is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should change loss function from reduce_mean to something differ. Your loss value is not changed during training. As first attempt you can try reduce_sum.